# Nginx: keep limiting the user for a duration

Tags: nginx, rate-limiting

I'm limiting the requests based on `CLIENT-KEY` header. The problem is that I need to keep sending the `429` status code for one minute after the header is limited. But with the current configuration, it lets the user to send another request after waiting for few seconds after receiving the first `429` response.

Here is my Nginx configuration:

```
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    limit_req_status 429;

    limit_req_zone $http_client_key zone=one:10m rate=10r/m;

    upstream api {
        server api:8080;
    }

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        location / {
            limit_req zone=one burst=10 nodelay;

            proxy_pass http://api;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if I got you right, you need to set `rate=1r/m;`

Comment: @user973254 No, I need to first limit 10 requests per minute and then, when the same `CLIENT-KEY` header is sent, it must be banned for 1 minute.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your needs it should be like this (didn't test):

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    limit_req_status 429;

    limit_req_zone $http_client_key zone=limit_ten_req_per_min:10m rate=10r/m;
    limit_req_zone $http_client_key zone=limit_ban_after_exceeded_limit:10m rate=1r/m;

    upstream api {
        server api:8080;
    }

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        location / {
            limit_req zone=limit_ten_req_per_min burst=10 nodelay;
            limit_req zone=limit_ban_after_exceeded_limit delay=1;

            proxy_pass http://api;
        }
    }
}
```

You set first `zone` (not sure if you actually want to have `burst=10` there), then there goes second one which is handles 1 request per minute (for more flexibility you can use [this](https://www.getpagespeed.com/nginx-mod-a-better-faster-nginx-build) 3rd party nginx module). Also you need `delay` in second zone to actually restrict further requests.

Comment: This limits the requests immediately after the first request.

Comment: @hhhal ok, I'm still not sure if this two-rule thing will work, but try to change `delay=1;`  to `delay=10;`, according to my thoughts, it should give to client opportunity to perform exact 10 queries and then will delay others.

Comment: unfortunately still the same result.

Comment: @hhhal could you poste here your `siege` log or screenshot, or other tool you testing with?

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/Hq13fGv/Screen-Shot-2022-05-03-at-6-00-02-PM.png

Comment: @hhhal sorry, but I can't reproduce it by myself, what is your config of `upstream api`?

Comment: I run the entire stack using a docker compose file which you can find at https://pastebin.com/ZzDSmCkg

Comment: @hhhal I can't figure out why it is not working, but  at least this might be helpful: https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/#Two-Stage-Rate-Limiting